# Can mysql tables do calculations like Excel?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns.

Column A contain numbers.

Column B contain numbers.

Column C is empty.

Is there a way where I can get the sum of column A and column B into column C like in excel =sum(a1+b1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do math in your SELECT statements.

```
SELECT price, tax, price+tax AS total
FROM orders
```

This will give you three columns: `price` and `tax` are direct from the row, and `total` is calculated on the fly when the SELECT is executed.

You *could* update a third column like this:

```
UPDATE orders
SET total=price+tax
```

and that would update the `total` column in every row, but that is unnecessary and is bad practice.  You don't need to store the values when they can be calculated on the fly.